# c++ typeid returns different values for the same unique_ptr with get() and *

Tags: c++, inheritance, unique-ptr, rtti, typeid

I came across one piece of code where `typeid` is used to get the type of a `unique_ptr` pointing to a polymorphic object.

```
class B{virtual void foo()= 0;};
class D:public B{void foo() override{}};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<B> bd = make_unique<D>();
    if (typeid(*bd) != typeid(bd.get()))
    {
        cout<<"Object types are not same"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Type name of *bd.name():      "<<typeid(*bd).name()<<endl;
    cout<<"Type name of bd.get().name(): "<<typeid(bd.get()).name()<<endl;
}
```

The output is :

```
Object types are not of same 
Type name of *bd.name():      1D 
Type name of bd.get().name(): P1B
```

The output of `name()` is different for [get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) and dereferencing with *. One more observation is that when there is no virtual functions defined in the class [without `void foo()` in above example], both get() and * prints same output.

Questions :

Why the get() and * gives different output when there is no virtual functions in the class ?

Live example : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tiy-Cn

EDIT-1
As per [* on a unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*), it says **"Returns the object owned by *this, equivalent to *get()."**

Comment: What are you talking about "no virtual functions in class"?  `virtual void foo`?!

Comment: I would use `dynamic_cast<>()` insted.

Comment: @Galik, I am also not a very big fan of typeid, just got confused! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`*bd` returns a reference.

`bd.get()` returns a pointer.

---

Re: your edit: Note that it says *"equivalent to *get()"* and not *"equivalent to get()"*.

Comment: BTW I am just wondering why someone would use *get() instead of just * ?

Comment: @Sitesh There's no reason to do that. But the specification can just define it that way for simplicity.